# How do I make imports work for file that need to be called from different folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my folder structure

```
├── folder1
│   ├── component.py
│   └── utils
│       └── utils.py
└── rootComponent.py
```

`component.py` makes use of utils. So I import it with

```
import utils
```

but if I try to import `component.py` from `rootComponent.py`

```
import folder1.component
```

I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

If I change the way I import utils in `component.py` to

```
import folder1.utils
```

Then it works from `rootComponent.py`, but it stops working from `component.py`, when I run it on its own

How can I import utils in `component.py` so that it works both if I run the script on its own or if I import it from `rootComponent.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an ad-hoc and dirty solution can be done with a try-except block:

```py
# in component.py
try:
    import utils
except:
    import folder1.utils
```

another solution is to modify the [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). python searches paths listed here for import requests after it searched the current folder and python's standard library. hence, by adding the `folder1` to this list, we can import any of its contents, independent from the script's execution path (as long as there is no name collision though)

```py
# in rootComponent.py
import sys

sys.path.append('folder1') # but this path is relative. if you want absolute independence, provide the full path from the root.

import component, utils
```